# Проблема при копировании кода

Tags: java, intellij-idea, windows-10, перекодировка, копирование

```
public static void createFileAndWriteResponseToFileWithNameOfCurrentDate(List<String> lines) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        String fileName = formatter.format(date) + ".txt";
        log.debug("Create file: " + fileName);
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Files.write(file.toPath(), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
```

Во время копирования кода, строка `createFileAndWriteResponseToFileWithNameOfCurrentDate`
изменяется на
`createFileGPw8VKLNYvjEPgqLbhZQwnD21Kri8ojgakKfAAVbate`.
**Почему?**

Если копировать строку по частям, например вот так:
`createFileAndWriteResponse`+ `ToFileWithNameOfCurrentDate`

то нормально копирует, поэтому думаю что проблема не с кодировкой.

Comment: Защита от копирования?

Comment: @Олексій-Моренець Не понял вопроса. Данный код написал я и защиты от копирования осознанно не делал. Сможете ссылку скинуть, чтобы понять что конкретно вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: createFileAndWriteResponseToFileWithNameOfCurrentDate. Скопировалось нормально

Comment: createFileAndWriteResponseToFileWithNameOfCurrentDate. Из кода тоже

Comment: @Олексій-Моренець А какая у вас операционная система?
Такая же проблема возникает прикопировании текста, где много символов подряд идут английские буквы без пробелов. Например при копировании публичной ссылки `https://github.com/AlexeyOs/Alexey/commit/11fdd69423c17edf2b77d87d585959a4f2b51af7` получается `https://github.com/AlexeyOs/Alexey/commit/1NCcGPw8VKMeoDHjNth1NQgyKzFzhAne8H2orZf7`

Comment: Андроид какойто. На винде 10 тоже норм копирует